# Change camel route parameters at runtime

Tags: apache-camel

I want to transfer file from endpoint A to endpoint B depending on actual date.

```
myFileNamePattern=
     String.format("(.)*%s.json",LocalDate.now().format("yyyymmdd"));

 from("endpointA").filter((header(AWS2S3Constants.KEY).regex(myFileNamePattern))).to("endpointB);
```

The route will only consume files that have the same date as the creation date of the route and won't transfer files for next dates.

What can I do to change the date in my file name pattern at runtime without stopping and restarting the route ?

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is dynamic, you could (for instance) use a **bean** to implement the filtering logic:

```
MyDynamicFilter mdf = new MyDynamicFilter();

from("endpointA")
    .filter().method(mdf, "withSameDate")
    .to("...);

public MyDynamicFilter {

  private String pattern;

  public synchronized void updatePattern(String newPattern) {
    this.pattern = newPattern;
  }

  public boolean withSameDate(@Header(AWS2S3Constants.KEY) String header) {
  ... // compare with this.pattern
  }


}
```